# New tag to address questions regarding conduct of artists and craftspeople

Tags: discussion, faq, tags, tag-scope

To address questions about the (acceptability of) (professional) behaviour of artists or craftspeople, and to avoid them being tagged with irrelevant tags, I created the [artistic-conduct](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artistic-conduct) tag.

As usage guidance I wrote the following:

> For questions concerning the professionalism of behaviour of artists or craftspeople of any skill level. This includes the use of autographs, and the use (and abuse) of reproductions.

I added the tag to some existing questions as reference.

**Does this seem like a practical tag, and a proper phrasing of both the tag itself and its wiki excerpt?**
Is there an alternative method to deal with questions that are tagged incorrectly because appropriate tags are missing?

Comment: TBH, my own opinion is that it isn't a good tag. I'm not sure the subject matter (as defined in the wiki), is really on-topic. But beyond that, people rarely read the wiki guidance, so the tag name needs to be unambiguous. The tag isn't intuitive, so it isn't likely to get selected by the poster. If it's added by a site regular, it isn't likely to be helpful as something people would think to use as a search term to look for existing Q&A. If a poster does use it, they are likely to misuse it or apply their own meaning to it, so we'd end up with a motley collection of questions with the tag.

Comment: Very good points. I think you're right. Do you think an alternative term could improve the matter, or does it seem to be a lost cause? An additional problem is that people tend to tag those posts with tags that don't apply to the question at all, simply because they need to use a tag (I'll add that to the body of my question later).

Comment: Yeah, one of the problems with tags is that they grow organically with the site.  A&C is still in its infancy, and the library of tags reflects that.  It would be easier if sites defined a taxonomy for their subject matter, which would provide some structure for tags.  The process is kind of done in reverse, where people try to formalize some structure based on what gets posted.  It's also a challenge to come up with tag names that are intuitively what people will think to use when they post or search.  (cont'd)

Comment: Maybe the first step on this one is to get a reading on whether artistic conduct falls within the site scope.  It could be that nobody has thought about that yet.  This question could serve to collect input on that from the community.

Comment: Artist conduct does fall within A&C’s scope, it seems to me, because this is a very definable, objective, relevant/real life set of issues. I think however that very specific tags such as “copy-write infringement”, “use of reproductions” and/or “use of autographs”, and any tags for other specific conduct issues that arise, would work better than the broad “artist conduct” tag, in agreement with @fixer1234’s reasoning above.

Comment: Yes, you're both right. I removed the tags, and made a new 'copyright' tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, tags like this would probably only belong on off-topic questions.

For reference: questions about the *business side* of art are *not* on topic:

[Are questions about the business side of selling your craft/art on-topic?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/are-questions-about-the-business-side-of-selling-your-craft-art-on-topic)

Copyright, trademark, selling, network building, distribution, etc., are all examples of questions that don't fit our scope. Arts & Crafts is meant to be specifically about the things that go into *making* the physical piece, and not the steps that (often) come afterwards.